# Docker push with artifactory

Tags: ssl, nginx, docker, artifactory, proxies

I am trying to create a local docker repository where I can push my images into.For this I have done the following steps

Configured nginx with SSL
Configured nginx so that it binds the docker local repo with the server name
Following is my nginx configuration

```
upstream artifactory_lb {
        server myLb.company.com:8081;
        server myLb.company.com:8081 backup;
}

log_format upstreamlog '[$time_local] $remote_addr - $remote_user - $server_name  to: $upstream_addr: $request upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time msec $msec request_time $request_time';

server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/my-certs/myCert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/my-certs/myserver.key;
        client_max_body_size 2048M;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_pass http://artifactory_lb;
                proxy_read_timeout 90;
        }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstreamlog;
        location /basic_status {
                stub_status on;
                allow all;
                }
}

# Server configuration

server {
    listen 2222 ssl;

    server_name myLb.company.com;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
        set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
    }

    rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /api/docker/my_local_repo_key/$1/$2;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;
    location / {
    proxy_read_timeout  900;
    proxy_pass_header   Server;
    proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
    proxy_pass         http://artifactory_lb;
    proxy_set_header   X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

When I try to push a docker image - `docker push https://myLb.comapny.com/docker/api/image_name` I get the following error

```
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://myLb.company.com/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Note: I did check the authority of the certificate and the other repositories in artifactory work with no issues

Also installed the certificate under /etc/docker/certs.d and etc/ssl/ca-certificates and usr/local/share/ca-certificates

What am I missing?

Comment: Does `myCert.pem` include any necessary intermediate certificates?

Comment: No, afaik I received a .der certificate which I then converted to .pem with openssl.

Comment: Check your certificate provider's FAQ and see if you need an intermediate certificate.

Comment: I dont think it does, I am able to connect java clients to maven repos, but not docker clients. Seems more like a docker issue or with the registry url mapping?

Comment: Should the intermediate certificates also be installed on the docker client?

Comment: No, only the `nginx` server. Basically you need to append them to `myCert.pem`.

Comment: Is this different for a docker client? Java clients do not need an intermediate certificate and cam work with the .pem certificate

Comment: I tried installing teh chain certificate still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the certificate chain from the Nginx config.

See: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains

How you get this chain certificate (intermediate certificate) depends on your certificate authority. You should be able to find it via your CA instructions. For example, for GoDaddy, the [instructions](https://www.godaddy.com/help/installing-an-ssl-certificate-nginx-6722) point you towards this repository where you can find the intermediate certificate chain: https://certs.godaddy.com/repository